# Save record to multiple tables using UoW pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am using MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6 and Unit of Work pattern.

**Tables: and fields**

Customer - Id, Name

ContactType - Id, Name (Home contact, work contact etc)

ContactDetails - Id, CustomerId, ContactTypeId, ContactValue

One Customer can have multiple Contact Details (so Customer1 has a home contact, work contact etc).

The ContactType table is a look-up table so it just displays the types of contacts available (home, work, emergency, mobile etc)

I have created the Interfaces and Classes as required to carry out the basic Add, Edit functionality, then created an **Unit Of Work** class to hold **all** these Repositories.

Tested it out and everything works as expected when i hard code values in.

When i created my MVC application, i added the below lines to add this entry into a database using the Unit of Work class

```
    public ActionResult SaveContactDetails(CustomerContactType viewModel)
    {
        _unitOfWork.Customers.Add(viewModel.Customer);
        _unitOfWork.ContactDetails.Add(viewModel.ContactDetail);
        //_unitOfWork.SaveAllChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

I created a new ViewModel called CustomerContactType which is a class containing the tables i require in order to save the data successfully

```
    public class CustomerContactType
    {
        public ContactType ContactType { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public ContactDetail ContactDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

I realised how to assign a dropdown value to the model within the .cshtml, so the ContactDetails table knows which ContactType is associated with that contact number (Home, emergency etc).

The problem i have is the ContactDetails requires a customer ID. This customer ID doesnt generate until the customer is saved so im not sure how i should be doing this?

These two lines carry out the task but i can see the customerID is null in the second line where i would have preferred it to contain the ID

```
_unitOfWork.Customers.Add(viewModel.Customer);
_unitOfWork.ContactDetails.Add(viewModel.ContactDetail);
```

I can provide additional code if required but wasnt sure if theres an easy fix or not.

Comment: Hi, because in your class there is no id if you want to save it in a table?, is there the possibility of calling the values in jquery for the controller? in my view it would be easier

Comment: please post the whole classes code.Are you using code first?

Comment: @Serge Yes code first.... This would be a good place to see the code https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern/

Comment: You should always post a [mcve] whenever possible. We should have all of your classes. Posting definitions like `ContactDetails - Id, CustomerId, ContactTypeId, ContactValue` is just hard work for us. Always post your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CustomerId in ContactDetails, why not change CustomerId to be of a complex type Customer and decorate it with a foreign key attribute? That way you can add a ContactDetails object along with a Customer object assigned to its property and a single call to SaveChanges should persist both entities to the DB.

Comment: Ive updated my original thread to explain what im doing. The reason why there is a CustomerID in the ContactDetails table is so i know which customer has what contactType? Do you have an example i could follow? As im not sure how it would resolve the above issue?